# Track hardware for hanging plywood panels

Tags: hardware

I have been looking all over for specific hardware that allows panels to be mounted with the rail hook mounted to a notch. This pdf shows the mounting technique

https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/docresources/36446/119/1192091.pdf

I'm specifically looking for Metal Rail RM-0924 and the rail hook RM-0834. Anyone know of anything similar out there pls let me know.

[image]

The intention here is to be able to mount plywood boards (e.g. 1x8') for shelving vertically to the wall with the possibility of sliding them along the track if needed. Don't want to use cross braces. A mitered cleat on the 1/2" ply by itself isn't strong enough and will tear under some load. The rail hook reinforces it enough to take on over 300LB. Also as you would see in the PDF the back of the shelf stays flush against the wall. Very clean and very convenient with a bit of metal.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Shopping questions are off-topic for here. But there are numerous options for hanging things in a similar manner, most of which don't involve any commercial fixing system. The one that most immediately comes to mind is what is now popularly known as the French cleat. But it's worth mentioning that simply screwing the item directly to the wall, using appropriate screws and plugs or wall anchors, is a viable alternative if quick lift-on/lift-off mounting isn't a priority.

Comment: The link you posted is PFD.  I do not download PFD's. A photo or a web link would be helpful. Also,  more detail in the question may clarify  your intentions.

Comment: Oh man, just reading that PDF made me break out in Ikea hives all over. Seriously, just google French cleat or maybe cabinet wall-hanging cleat. You're bound to come up with at least several ideas. Also, try your search with the two part numbers at the end of the search string. I'd bet it's 50/50 that you even happen upon a reference to the parts you seek.

Comment: @Jim, "Ikea hives" hahahaha, I love it.

Comment: @AlaskaMan do you feel the same about PDFs? :)

Comment: Thanks others for the helpful hints. Btw this was from some company from Canada. But IKEA forever!  @Jim this is not a french cleat which I make regularly. Googled quite a bit and hence the post.

Comment: @Fakeer   opps. I have PFD on the brain this time of year. Here in Alaska every citizen gets a PFD (Permanent Fund, Dividend)  in October every year from oil revenues. PFD, Is also a personal flotation devise.

Comment: Ironically, I have a project right now that would benefit from this, though I was going to make a french cleat. But something lower profile would be cool.

Comment: If any alternative hanging ideas aren't to your liking for this you can build something like these brackets from plywood, if you can't find the metal ones within a reasonable timeframe.

Comment: "*A mitered cleat on the 1/2" ply by itself isn't strong enough and will tear under some load.*" (*Does it have to be 1/2" ply?*) I think that is a false assumption. An artist friend of mine rotates his very large, very heavy oil on MDF and board paintings, off and on, side to side, repeatedly  on 1//2" ply, or thinner, french cleats and has done for years.  The french cleat does not need to be made of wood, it can be aluminum or steel.

Answer (score 1):

"Sliding rail" and "rail hooks" are the search terms you are looking for. See places like [McMaster-Carr sliding tracks](https://www.mcmaster.com/sliding-tracks/), at least as a start.

If this does not suffice, as it looks like your reference design is custom, you can consider modifying the common t-slot designs used in many commercial applications. We've all seen the "wall of slotted engineered veneer" at stores with matching installations that hook and slide on with keyed sliders.

The rail could be a robust plywood with one or more slots in it (so you could adjust for height, as well!) and the runners would key in similarly within insets.

Maybe not the turnkey solution you are looking for, but that may only be available in B2B markets. You may have to trade off making your own solution now for some perfect solution you hope to find in the future.

Amazon and places like Lee Valley offer examples and (usually router) tooling to make your own.

To recap:

1. You might find the exact hardware with more internet sleuthing, though it appears you've exhausted most avenues, leaving you with the long tail of searching B2B manufacturers.
2. French cleats. Not perfect for your application, as the inset and top rail might get a bit large. But very cheap, and easily made in the home shop. Metal cleats purchased from any online shop could be very low-profile.
3. T-Slot (or whatever letter is appropriate) design similar to a French cleat that would be a little more complicated to make, but could be made a little lower profile that traditional French cleats.

Note: I know that some folks refer to the latter two both as "French cleats" But I'm making a distinction here. There is what I think is the traditional cleat, made from convenient lumber (or metal) as a pair of simple mating surfaces. The slotted design is more of a commercial system that usually requires a router with some special tooling, and specific keyed runners. But you may run into places that conflate the two. (I don't care who's definition is correct -- I'm making a distinction for the purpose of answering the question "how can I solve my problem in a similar manner as the described hardware".)

It also depends if you *require* the unit to move smoothly, as if on bearings or wheeled tracks. If so, none of this advice will do, and you will need to shop for a solution, or engineer up a very interesting solution.

Comment: My vote to close is already recorded, but I'll say it in the open — shopping question!

Comment: @Graphus, yeah it is pretty close, especially since the OP has specifically said no to french cleats. Honestly, I'm considering this hardware for a current project, but it is hardly "woodworking", even if I make my own french cleats. I did abstained from voting because I was hoping it could be more of a "how do I?" But, given the no french cleats rule, not sure what we can offer.

Comment: If we just put my search terms in a comment and close it, I can be convinced.

Comment: @jdv searched there (as you might have as well). i think tracks are generic and can be found easily. i'm wondering if the hook can be DIY out of aluminium on CNC?

Comment: *"i'm wondering if the hook can be DIY out of aluminium on CNC? "* Well that route could most certainly generate the pieces, but aluminium is not the ideal metal for this application (ali is a 'smeary' metal that has a habit of binding under high load/high friction). And anyway like I said above, you *can* make such brackets successfully from plywood. But honestly I can't see any reason you can't use "French cleats" here and just save yourself a load of time, money and hassle. If you doubt this is strong enough a modest amount of Googling will reassure you I promise.

Comment: It depends on if you really want them to move all the time, or if this is a convenience for left-right positioning only. If the latter, then aluminum will probably be fine. If not, then you need to match the metals for the runners and tracks, or one will always win the hardness war with interesting results.

Comment: This is a solution in search of a problem (for a woodworker at least)! OP already knows about "French cleats", which give exactly what he wants in terms of functionality way faster — he'd be done already — at *significantly* lower cost.... imagine what the CNC charge might be versus an off-the-shelf product. Then there's P&P on top.

Comment: @Graphius, the one single win I see of the OPs design wish is how it tucks in for near-zero-tolerance fit to the wall, and does so for on-edge designs. This is a pretty nice use of the materials for the kind of flatpack furniture it is intended for. It won't solve my problem, however, now that I think about about it. My solution is pure old-fashioned french cleat.